# Using Tails via mobile hotspot

Tags: tails, virtual-machine

MY PC WAS HACKED RECENTLY due to which I'm exploring options to secure my Internet usage using Tails.

My question to all those cyber crime fighting folks. Would it be possible to track back my Internet usage if I'm using Tails(hosted on VirtualBox) and mobile hotspot to connect?

Your answers and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Running Tails in a VM is not recommended since the host OS and VirtualBox itself can see what you're doing inside the VM.

And if your host OS is infected/owned, the attacker can see what you do on Tails as well. I recommend reading [Tails warning page](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/warning/index.en.html) before doing anything. And maybe install Tails on a USB stick instead of running it on a VM.

And oh, the source of internet connection doesn't matter. Since everything will be sent over Tor.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestions. My follow up question is if I install Tails on USB stick, then I would have to restart the PC to boot Tails correct?

Comment: Correct, but if your PC was hacked then your current host operating system is probably untrustworthy. Running tails inside of a VM from it would make tails vulnerable to whatever the host operating system was and making the host "ephemeral" is difficult. e.g. pagefile/swap/hibernation will all result in your host OS writing the virtual memory of the tails VM to disk, leaving traces of your tails usage on persistent storage, breaking some it's anti-forensic properties.

Comment: Thank was very helpful. So if I'm using just Tails on USB without using IPVanish like softwares, would it mean that people would not be able to track my laptop or IP address?

Comment: unless either your hardware or boot process are infected.